# Controller Action receiving old values as parameters on AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm sending an Ajax Request to my MVC Action in ASP.NET using simple jquery, it works fine for the first time but after the first call, all calls tend to receive the first posted values on Action.

when I try to debug my JS code new values are populated there but on Action, they change back to the first ones.

my Jquery Code:

```
  $('.send-quote').click(function (e) {
  var $form = $('#manualBooking');

            var formData = $('#manualBooking').serializeArray();

            var name = formData[0].value;
            var contact = formData[1].value;
            var email = formData[2].value;
            var bookingDate = formData[3].value;
            var pickupLocation = formData[4].value;
            var dropOffLocation = formData[5].value;
            var flight = formData[6].value;
            var passenger = formData[7].value;
            var luggage = formData[8].value;
            var message = formData[9].value;
            var language = formData[10].value;
            var hours = formData[11].value;
            var days = formData[12].value;
            var radio = formData[13].value;


            if (radio == 'yes') {

                $form.validate({
                    errorClass: 'customErrorClass',
                    rules: {
                        name: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        phone: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        email: {
                            required: true,
                            email: true
                        },
                        depdate: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        txtAddresspickupFromAirport: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        txtAddressdropOffFromAirport: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        flight: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        passenger: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        luggage: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        message: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        lang: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        hours: {
                            required: true
                        },
                        days: {
                            required: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        email: "*Please specify a valid email address"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) {
                        console.log(' NOT OK')
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '/Home/InsertManualBookingForm',
                            data: {
                                Name: name,
                                ContactNo: contact,
                                Email: email,
                                BookingDateTime: bookingDate,
                                PickUpLocation: pickupLocation,
                                DropOffLocation: dropOffLocation,
                                FlightNumber: flight,
                                Passenger: passenger,
                                Luggage: luggage,
                                Message: message,
                                Language: lang,
                                HoursNeeded: hours,
                                DaysNeeded: days
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                swal("an email will be sent to you shortly", {
                                    icon: "success",
                                });

                                //   document.getElementById("manualBooking").reset();


                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
```

and my MVC action code:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "none")]
    public JsonResult InsertManualBookingForm(ManualBookingForm manualBookingForm)
    {

        this.ModelState.Clear();
        ModelState.Clear(); // force to use new model values

        String Result = String.Empty;
        this.ModelState.Clear();
        ModelState.Clear(); // force to use new model values


        try
        {
            string agentCardsSerialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(manualBookingForm);

        this.ModelState.Clear();
            ModelState.Clear(); // force to use new model values



            Result = Common.Common.ApiCall(Common.Common.APIEndpoint + "Home/InsertManualBookingForm", agentCardsSerialize);//Common.Common.ApiCall(URL_Request, commisionType,token);
            return Json(Result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```

as you can see I even tried the online solutions of emptying the cache and clearing the Model State but no solution seems to work.

is there a problem with my AJAX call or MVC action? please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Adding cache:false in your ajax call

```
  $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '/Home/InsertManualBookingForm',
                            cache:false,
                            data: {
                                Name: name,
                                ContactNo: contact,
                                Email: email,
                                BookingDateTime: bookingDate,
                                PickUpLocation: pickupLocation,
                                DropOffLocation: dropOffLocation,
                                FlightNumber: flight,
                                Passenger: passenger,
                                Luggage: luggage,
                                Message: message,
                                Language: lang,
                                HoursNeeded: hours,
                                DaysNeeded: days
                            },
                            success: function (data) {
                                swal("an email will be sent to you shortly", {
                                    icon: "success",
                                });

                                //   document.getElementById("manualBooking").reset();


                            }
                        });
```

Lets us know if it works

**PS** : Get the values of the form (Name, ContactNo, Email ... etc ) in **submit handler** right before ajax call, probably thats the reason it is always taking the values from the first call.

Comment: this worked for me, I needed to get the values before submit handler

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the missing attribute [FromBody] is the problem but you can try and see.

```
public JsonResult InsertManualBookingForm([FromBody]ManualBookingForm manualBookingForm)
{
   //Your code
}
```

Comment: `[FromBody]` is a web-api attribute and has nothing to do with asp.net-mvc

Comment: True. This request could be to an API, might make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, after operation try this :

```
 ModelState.Remove("ManualBookingForm ");
```